# MySQL : select 2 times the same field with differents values

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I need to have in the same select 2 times the same columns but with differents values. I tried INNER JOIN, etc ... But I have no idea, I don't find the answer

This is my DB `switch` :

```
+----------+-------------+
| switchID | patchCordID |
+----------+-------------+
|        2 |        NULL |
|      197 |           1 |
|        1 |           1 |
+----------+-------------+
```

I need to find all switch which have the same `patchCordID` than the `switchID 197`.

The select will looks like : `SELECT switchID, patchCordID, switchID2` with `switchID = 197` and `switchID2 = 1`.

The select shows that the both switch are connected.

Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand this, could you explain a bit, what would be your expected result from the given sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sw1.switchID, sw1.patchCordID, sw2.switchID as switchID2
from switch sw1
join switch sw2 on sw1.patchCordID=sw2.patchCordID
where sw1.switchID=197
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, a nested select should do the trick.

```
select switchID, patchCordID from switch 
where patchCordID=(select patchCordID from switch where switchID=197)
```

This will give you a results set of all switches with their patchCordIDs that share the patchCordID of switchID 197.

If your `switchID` isn't unique you would use `in` instead:

```
select switchID, patchCordID from switch 
where patchCordID in (select distinct patchCordID from switch where switchID=197)
```

Comment: If `pathcordID` is unique column, this should works. Otherwise, what if `(select patchCordID from switch where switchID=197)` returns more than one row?

Comment: Yes, It works @swornabsent, but switchID isn't 2 times on my select, that's the point.. I need both on my result

Comment: And @RubahMalam, yes it does

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, you would get the switchID 1 result in its own row, can you explain why you need it on the same line? Think about if you had 500 switches with matching patchCordIDs, do you expect to have switchID2...switchID500 in your select?

Comment: Indeed, maybe that it's to hard to make... Should I just have the patchcordID and the switchID ?

Comment: Based on what I know from your question that'd be my recommendation, yes. Should be simple enough to iterate over the results.